# open excel files in browser with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vbscript

I use Vbscript and i would like to open excel files in browser and not to download them as external files. Is there any possible way to do that? Is it possible with javascript?  They could be opened at a new slide over the current window

Comment: simple answer: no, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to open an Excel document in a browser.

1. Have a browser plugin that can handle Excel
2. Convert the data to HTML

To do that latter would require an Excel parser. I'm not aware of any existing JavaScript ones, so you would have to find one or write one. Writing one would possibly be easier if you looked at an open source implementation in another language and ported it.